# Sitecore Claims - How do I get it to work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, sitecore, adfs

I am very new to Sitecore.
I am converting a web forms application to a Sitecore application where I make an ADFS call and get the user to login. The application returns a Claims object with the `Name` and `EmailAddress`.
However, in case of Sitecore, I read that Sitecore directly implements `IIdentity` and `IPrincipal` and hence is not possible to utilize the Claims with Sitecore Identity and User (Principal).

I've tried referring to [this article](http://cprakash.com/2015/02/02/sitecore-with-claimsidentity/). 
And downloaded and installed the [ADFS.Authentication package](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/ADFSAuthenticator.aspx).

I have also made changes to the web.config as mentioned in the article.
As i understand, all I need to do is call the Login method:

```
AuthenticationManager.Login(userId, false);
```

However, when I run, I get this error:

> AuthenticationHelper has not been set. It must be set in Initialize.

How should I proceed? As I understand, by downloading the ADFS.Authentication package, I do not need to do anything and this should take care of converting the claims too. Is my understanding correct?
Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented something similar in the past and to get this working I've setup my own Httpmodule to handle the communication back and forth from the remote systems and I did not implement IPrincipal.

Then when authenticated, I log in the user as a Sitecore virtual user and store any information in an encrypted forms cookie, this keeps things nice and simple and you don't have to worry about anything conflicting with Sitecore.

More info on virtual users here:

http://www.sitecoreinsight.com/lightweight-authentication-using-virtual-users-in-sitecore/

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I may be looking for!